# Get AutoFilter sort criteria and apply on second sheet

Tags: sorting, vba, excel, autofilter

I'm trying to see if I can programatically trap an AutoFilter sort event, get the sort criteria and then apply that same sort criteria to an AutoFilter in a second worksheet.

So far it seems as though I have to trigger the Worksheet_Calculate() event. And this I've done. Then I have to check if the AutoFilter sort criteria was changed. If it wasn't, exit sub. If it was, collect the criteria and run it through a separate sub, which does the exact same sorting on an AutoFilter in a separate worksheet.

The general idea is that whenever one of these two AutoFilters are sorted, the AutoFilter in the other sheet should be sorted the exact same way.

I've tried to do something like this (I had to add an Excel formula to actually make the calculate event trigger):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
     Dim wbBook as Workbook
     Dim wsSheet as Worksheet
     Dim rnData as Range

     Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
     Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

     With wsSheet
          Set dnData = .UsedRange
     End With
End Sub
```

But I can't seem to manage to collect the criteria, I've tried several things and adding a watch to the dnData doesn't even reveal any AutoFilter property. Can someone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to get the `autofilter` criteria:

```
Sub test()
Dim Header As Range
Dim sMainCrit As String, sANDCrit As String, sORCrit As String
Set Header = Range("A2:C2")
    With Header.Parent.AutoFilter
        With .Filters(Header.Column - .Range.Column + 1)
            If Not .On Then
                MsgBox ("no criteria")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            sMainCrit = .Criteria1
            If .Operator = xlAnd Then
                sANDCrit = .Criteria2
            ElseIf .Operator = xlOr Then
                sORCrit = .Criteria2
            End If
        End With
    End With
    MsgBox ("Main criteria: " & sMainCrit & Chr(13) & "AND Criteria:" & sANDCrit & Chr(13) & "OR Criteria" & sORCrit)
End Sub
```

Adapted from [ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-criteria.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some notes on what I see as your requirements.

```
Dim rv As AutoFilter ''Object
Set rv = Sheet1.AutoFilter

''Just for curiosity
Debug.Print rv.Sort.Header
Debug.Print rv.Sort.SortFields.Count
Debug.Print rv.Sort.SortFields.Item(1).SortOn
Debug.Print rv.Sort.Rng.Address
Debug.Print rv.Sort.SortFields.Item(1).Key.Address

''One key only, but it is easy enough to loop and add others
Sheet2.Range(rv.Sort.Rng.Address).Sort _
    key1:=Sheet2.Columns(rv.Sort.SortFields(1).Key.Column), _
    Header:=xlYes
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this code:

```
Sub ShowAutoFilterCriteria()
' John Green et. al: Excel 2000 VBA Programmer?s Reference, S. 379f
' 09.01.2005
Dim oAF As AutoFilter
Dim oFlt As Filter
Dim sField As String
Dim sCrit1 As String
Dim sCrit2 As String
Dim sMsg As String
Dim i As Integer

' Check if the sheet is filtered at all
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
MsgBox "The sheet does not have an Autofilter"
Exit Sub
End If

' Get the sheet?s Autofilter object
Set oAF = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter

' Loop through the Filters of the Autofilter
For i = 1 To oAF.Filters.Count

' Get the field name form the first row
' of the Autofilter range
sField = oAF.Range.Cells(1, i).Value

' Get the Filter object
Set oFlt = oAF.Filters(i)

' If it is on...
If oFlt.On Then

' Get the standard filter criteria
sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & sField & oFlt.Criteria1

' If it?s a special filter, show it
Select Case oFlt.Operator
Case xlAnd
sMsg = sMsg & " And " & sField & oFlt.Criteria2
Case xlOr
sMsg = sMsg & " Or " & sField & oFlt.Criteria2
Case xlBottom10Items
sMsg = sMsg & " (bottom 10 items)"
Case xlBottom10Percent
sMsg = sMsg & " (bottom 10%)"
Case xlTop10Items
sMsg = sMsg & " (top 10 items)"
Case xlTop10Percent
sMsg = sMsg & " (top 10%)"
End Select
End If
Next i

If msg = "" Then
' No filters are applied, so say so
sMsg = "The range " & oAF.Range.Address & " is not filtered."
Else
' Filters are applied, so show them
sMsg = "The range " & oAF.Range.Address & " is filtered by:" & sMsg
End If

' Display the message
MsgBox sMsg
End Sub
```

Works fine on my tests! I've changed a small part of it to support complex criteria:

```
' Get the standard filter criteria
If IsArray(oFlt.Criteria1) Then
    Dim x As Integer
    sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & sField
    For x = 1 To UBound(oFlt.Criteria1)
        sMsg = sMsg & "'" & oFlt.Criteria1(x) & "'"
    Next x
Else
    sMsg = sMsg & vbCrLf & sField & "'" & oFlt.Criteria1 & "'"
End If
```

Original link: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-7564.html