# AutoFilter - Dynamically change in Filter Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having the same kind of question as in this link - 
[Get AutoFilter sort criteria and apply on second sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764655/get-autofilter-sort-criteria-and-apply-on-second-sheet)

I've gone thru the link but not able to get the required output.

I've the filtered criteria in Sheet1 (which we can change as required) on one of the column values (eg: col 10) and now based on what ever the data in column 10 which are shown based on the filter criteria, I want to filter on sheet2 with the data in sheet 1.

I have seen that many of them using with static values in ARRAY as shown but how can I autofilter dynamically changing values in the sheet1 and filtering in Sheet2. Please advise

`.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array("value1", "value2"), Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsCriteria As Worksheet
    Dim arrCriteria As Variant

    Set wsData = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set wsCriteria = Sheets("Sheet1")
    arrCriteria = Application.Transpose(wsCriteria.Range("J4", wsCriteria.Range("J4").End(xlDown)).Value)

    With wsData.UsedRange
        .AutoFilter 10, arrCriteria, xlFilterValues
    End With

    Set wsData = Nothing
    Set wsCriteria = Nothing
    If IsArray(arrCriteria) Then Erase arrCriteria

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi TigerAvatar, Thank you, With the above criteria, its selecting all the values in Sheet1, but the sheet 1 has the filtered values. When I modified it as : arrCriteria = Application.Transpose(wsCriteria.Range(wsCriteria.Cells(4, 10), wsCriteria.Cells(4, 10).End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Value), its taking only the first value and not the next values

Comment: Why are you using SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)? Do you have hidden rows where the criteria is? It would be best if the critiera list for the filter is a consecutive, unbroken list.

Comment: Yes, It has the Unbroken list. In my sheet 1, when I select the filter on one of the columns (column 10) , based on the Sheet1 data values in Column 10, I want to Filter in Sheet 2. So If I filter column 10 with 10 values in sheet1, based on 10 values in sheet1 , sheet 2 should be filtered. is it achievable?

Comment: So remove the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` so that it reads as

`arrCriteria = Application.Transpose(wsCriteria.Range("J4", wsCriteria.Range("J4").End(xlDown)).Value)`

Comment: not sure , its showing "Type Mismatch" error:     arrCriteria = Application.Transpose(wsCriteria.Range("J4", wsCriteria.Cells(Rows.count, "J").End(xlDown)).Value)

Comment: It works for me when I test it out, I have updated the code in the answer, give that a try.

Comment: its giving irregular results in the Sheet2. The arrCriteria = Application.Transpose(wsCriteria.Range("J4", wsCriteria.Range("J4").End(xlDown)).Value) is not taking the visible values. When I change the same statement to : arrCriteria = Application.Transpose(wsCriteria.Range("L4", wsCriteria.Range("L4").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Value) with special cells, its taking only value1 out of value1 and value2 in sheet1. Its working but its taking only value1, my expectation is take value1 and value2. Not sure, what I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

What if you just define the array in VBA?

```
Dim CritArray(2) as String
 CritArray(0) = Cells(1,1).Value
 CritArray(1) = Cells(2,1).Value
```

Then just editing your line of code:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array(CritArray(0),CritArray(1)), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I dont know how many criteria you have (or their location), but you can add/edit as such. I based this off the fact you only have 2 criteria, but it can be enlarged of course.